# Curie Temperature and Resistance

Tags: temperature, electrical-resistance

I am trying to find a curie temperature from a substance. However, I have a question.
What we were trying to do is to heat the substance while measuring it's resistance.
So now we got a graph of it where x axis is the temperature, and y axis is the resistance. The resistance keep rising as the temperature arise.
We heated the substance until 450 Celsius, keep the temperature for 10 minutes-ish, and let it cool down to room temperature.

Ideally, the heating and the cooling path should overlap, since what happened when the temperature is higher than Curie temperature is that the substance will lose its magnetic 'ability'.
But if the graphs don't overlap, what happened?
Did something happened after the Curie temperature that made the resistance in the cooling process is higher/lower than the heating process?
I need some insight.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does Curie temperature have to do with electrical resistance? Is your material ferromagnetic?

Comment: Yes, my material is ferromagnetic

Answer (score 0):

you probably *annealed* the sample, altering its crystalline structure and changing its bulk resistivity. You need to repeat the experiment, taking light microscope photos of electropolished and grain-boundary resolved samples before and after the temperature treatment step.